How to apply a sorting algorithm to array field whenever a value is added or changed?
I have a few array fields in my Sanity project that would work better if they were automatically sorted based on their values rather than having a user manually sort them.
I tried to create a custom component like this:
import type { ArrayOfObjectsInputProps } from 'sanity'


export function sortedArray(props: ArrayOfObjectsInputProps) {
  return props.renderDefault({
    ...props, onChange: (_patch) => {
      //@ts-ignore
      props.value?.sort(props.schemaType.options.sortFunc)
    }
  })
}

With something like this in my schema:
import { sortedArray } from '...'

//...

{
  //...
  components: { input: sortedArray },
  options: {
    //@ts-ignore
    sortFunc: (a, b) => { /* Sorting Algorithm */ },
}

But whatever I try, I can't get it to work.
